# (.) dot not showed in jquery regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I've this expression binded to a input field:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

but it let me digits only number and not the "dot" (.). Where is the problem?

^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{1,2})?$ <--- I also tried this and same problem

^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$ <-- I also tried this and same problem

The goal is to get a unsigned integer/float number with max 2 digits and only dot (not comma)

Comment: Please put the "also tried" comments into the question.

Comment: The dot is inside the optional group. If it's required, it shouldn't be optional.

Comment: And always say what your goal is, what results you're seeing, and why that surprises you.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the above regex.

Comment: . is optional sir...

Comment: your regex works. http://regex101.com/r/xA3mN2/1

Comment: Provide your failing attempt with all relevant code in question. Your issue doesn't come from the regex, maybe the input type or whatelse...

Comment: if you just want an number in input. try this `^[0-9]+$`

Comment: I used this plugin: http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input and this code into the page $('#promonew_price').filter_input({regex:'^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$'});

Comment: try `$('#promonew_price').filter_input({regex:"^[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"}); `

Comment: it doesn't work i think it is a plugin bug. I wrote to the developer

Answer (score 0):

The `?` here:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
                     ^
```

...means that the group in front of it is optional. So that means that if something matches the `^[0-9]+$` part, it's valid. If your goal is to require numbers to have a `.` (which would be a bit odd), remove the `?`.

You're also using a capture group. If you're just using this for validation, you don't want a capture group, just a non-capturing group: `(?:....)`:

```
^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

If your goal is to require at least one digit before the `.`, then one or two after it (making `"10"` an invalid input, for instance), here's the regex to validate that:

```
^\d+\.\d{1,2}$
```